# flutter import issue

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

flutter version: 3.3.8
AS version: 2022.2.1

when i trying run this project, im encounter this issue:

**Error: The argument type 'List<ShortcutType/*1*/>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<ShortcutType/*2*/>'.**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oP6Wd.png)

but the code was just fetch from upstream and i didnt moditfied anything.
then i follow the erro and find the file, i find the issue was caused by the way i import.
i try to change the relative import to package import, most of the error can be fixed, but there is one file: i declared an Enum, then i used this Enum in another page. Only this particular error is hard to fix, no matter i try to import the Enum by package import or relative import.

this is how i declare Enum
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YEPm.png)

this is the way i import the Enum
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iv88n.png)

Comment: You have two separate types both named `ShortcutType`.  It's hard to tell exactly why since you censored the paths in the screenshot.  A common cause is importing the same `.dart` file in inconsistent ways (e.g. when using a case-insensitive file system, using one capitalization of the path in one place and a different capitalization elsewhere).  The double-slashes (`//`) in one of your paths looks suspicious too.  Fix your `import`s so that they're consistent.

Comment: i move the declaration for Enum to a independent file, and import it by package import in two places, then the issue is resovled. but the strange thing is same project can be run in my two different colleagues